# SQL Server replacement for SET FMTONLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

SQL Server is deprecating `SET FMTONLY` after SQL Server 2012.
What I like about `SET FMTONLY` is it will return meta data for multiple recordsets for a given stored procedure.
SQL Server 2012 and later versions are providing `sp_describe_first_result_set` and `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` which only returns metadata for the first result set, not all result sets.
Does anyone know of a replacement for `SET FMTONLY` that will ignore parameters yet return metadata on the structure of columns for ALL result sets?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.X = @Parameter1
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.Y = @Parameter2 AND TABLE2.Z = @Parameter3
```

I need the columns for each resultset.  I've tried passing NULL for parameters, but that does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT TOP (0) * FROM TABLE1;` OR `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 1 = 0;` ?

Comment: Does  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-for-object-for-multiple-result-sets answer this?

Comment: Select top 0 will not work because it does not take into account parameters for the stored proc.  I should have added that in my original post.

Comment: Passing `NULL` should work, as `x = NULL` will always be false. You say you've tried this, but can you provide a proper example?

Comment: The answer might be NO. But what exactly do you want to achieve? There might be workaround.

Comment: I created a custom code generator that would inspect a stored procedure using SET FMTONLY.  This returns meta data about each result set in stored proc (column information).  I use the meta data to generate code.  Without SET FMTONLY, then there is no way to retrieve column data (data types) for each result set in a stored proc.

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/usage-and-benefits-of-using-with-result-sets-in-sql-server-2012.html